# eyes position after face alignement

Tags: image, matlab, math, image-processing

I have a problem to find the eyes center after the face alignement (imrotate)
[image: 1000306439_a1744969b8_1369_11099615@N00.jpg]

Here is the code :

```
img = imread('1000306439_a1744969b8_1369_11099615@N00.jpg');
eyes = [230 238; 126 124];
if length(size(IMG)) > 2
    img = rgb2gray(img);
end
subplot(1,2,1),imshow(img);hold on;
plot(eyes(1,:),eyes(2,:),'-rx'); hold off;
tg_a = diff(eyes(2,:))/diff(eyes(1,:));
angle = tg_a*(180/pi);
img_rot = imrotate(img, angle,'crop'); 
Cx = size(img,2)/2;
Cy = size(img,1)/2;
R_EyeX = (Cx+(eyes(1,1)-Cx)*cosd(tg_a)-(eyes(2,1)-Cy)*sind(tg_a));
R_EyeY = (Cy+(eyes(1,1)-Cx)*sind(tg_a)+(eyes(2,1)-Cy)*cosd(tg_a));
L_EyeX = (Cx+(eyes(1,2)-Cx)*cosd(tg_a)-(eyes(2,2)-Cy)*sind(tg_a));
L_EyeY = (Cy+(eyes(1,2)-Cx)*sind(tg_a)+(eyes(2,2)-Cy)*cosd(tg_a));
subplot(1,2,2),imshow(img_rot);hold on;
plot([R_EyeX L_EyeX],[R_EyeY L_EyeY],'-rx');hold off;
```

the result :
[image]

Comment: What problem do you have exactly? What is not working as expected?

Comment: after the rotation, I didn't find the new position of eyes

Comment: I guess `cosd(tg_a)`/`sind(tg_a)` should be `cos(tg_a)` or `cosd(angle)`. Also there is something wrong with your signs, as even with these corrections the rotation will be in the wrong direction. I still don't understand how `tg_a = diff(eyes(2,:))/diff(eyes(1,:))` defines an angle. Don't you need some trigonometry here? `tan`?

Answer (score 0):

the fixed code:

```
img = imread('1000306439_a1744969b8_1369_11099615@N00.jpg');
eyes = [230 238; 126 124];
if length(size(IMG)) > 2
    img = rgb2gray(img);
end
subplot(1,2,1),imshow(img);hold on;
plot(eyes(1,:),eyes(2,:),'-rx'); hold off;
tg_a = diff(eyes(2,:))/diff(eyes(1,:));
angle = tg_a*(180/pi);
tg_a = -angle * (pi/180);
img_rot = imrotate(img, angle,'crop'); 
Cx = size(img,2)/2;
Cy = size(img,1)/2;
R_EyeX = (Cx+(eyes(1,1)-Cx)*cos(tg_a)-(eyes(2,1)-Cy)*sin(tg_a));
R_EyeY = (Cy+(eyes(1,1)-Cx)*sin(tg_a)+(eyes(2,1)-Cy)*cos(tg_a));
L_EyeX = (Cx+(eyes(1,2)-Cx)*cos(tg_a)-(eyes(2,2)-Cy)*sin(tg_a));
L_EyeY = (Cy+(eyes(1,2)-Cx)*sin(tg_a)+(eyes(2,2)-Cy)*cos(tg_a));
subplot(1,2,2),imshow(img_rot);hold on;
plot([R_EyeX L_EyeX],[R_EyeY L_EyeY],'-rx');hold off;
```